# R: variable and function of same name

Tags: r, function

R allows function and variable to have same name. I tested it with **lm** function but when i created my own function, **k**, i get an error. Could someone tell what is my error

```
> k<-function(d){2*d}
> k(5)
[1] 10
> k
function(d){2*d}
> k<-c(1,2)
> k
[1] 1 2
> k(2)
Error: could not find function "k"
```

works fine with **lm** function

```
> lm<-2
> lm
[1] 2
> lm(airquality$Ozone~., data=airquality)

Call:
lm(formula = airquality$Ozone ~ ., data = airquality)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      Solar.R         Wind         Temp        Month          Day  
  -64.11632      0.05027     -3.31844      1.89579     -3.03996      0.27388  

> lm
[1] 2
```

Comment: You have defined and overwritten k in the user environment for the first instance. In the second instance, the defined `lm` does not overwrite the `stats::lm` function.

Comment: Also, while this is interesting, somebody needs to say _don't do this_.

Comment: @AdamQuek got it. does that mean if a function is defined in user environment then i cannot have a variable of same name?

Comment: @alistaire thanks for the tip. I won't do this in practice but to be a good programmer i want to understand the semantics

Comment: You're assigning objects to the local environment, which is the first environment in the search path. If R doesn't find the object there, it looks further through the search path, which you can see with `search()` or `searchpaths()`. [Reading.](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html)

Comment: Here's an easy read on [naming convention in R](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2012-2/RJournal_2012-2_Baaaath.pdf). Basically there isn't any naming convention, but there are some links in there that detail some tidy perspective. This should hopefully remove any need to give identical names to your function and vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AdamQuek commented, I believe that the reason why `lm <- 2` does not overwrite the `lm()` function in the `stats` package is because that function exists in a different namespace.  When you defined your function `k()`, you defined it in the local namespace, and then you overwrote it in the local namespace.

R has a set of rules for determining the order of which namespace it uses when evaluating variables/functions.  If you had defined `lm()` locally as:

```
lm <- function(x) { print(x) }
```

Then calling `lm("Hello World")` would indeed print "Hello World."  If you still wanted to use the version of `lm()` from the `stats` package, you could use the fully qualified name of that function:

```
stats::lm(...)
```

In other words, if you don't qualify the function, R will first search the local namespace, and then it will search in libraries you have loaded.

And as Alistaire commented, please *don't do this*.  In any programming language, you should avoid naming user defined functions after functions in commonly used packages/libraries.

Comment: thanks, does that mean in a particular namespace, a function and a variable cannot have same name

Comment: @learnlifelong Yes, this is my understanding.  You saw it yourself; the variable `k` can only be one thing locally, either a function, or later a variable, as you assigned/defined it.